# DB design with parentID

Tags: sql

I would like to create the following hierarchy in a sql db. This is what I have. Is it correct or is there an easier way. Also how do I query it to show the same hierarchy?

```
Services
    Property
        Residential
            To let
                Purchase
                Accommodation
                Maintenance
                Plumbers
                Electricians
                Carpenters
       Industrial
    To let
                 Purchase
                 Accommodation
                 Maintenance
                 Plumbers
                 Electricians
                 Carpenters
```

Table `CategoryType`

```
CategoryTypeID CategoryName
1   Services
2   Products
3   Main
4   MainSub
5   Sub
6   Sub1
```

Table `Category`

```
CateogryID      CategoryName   CategoryTypeID  ParentID
1       Property    Service
2       Residential Main        1
3        To let     MainSub 2
4       Purchase    Sub     3
5       Accommodation Sub       4
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema may work, but RDBMSs are notoriously difficult to work with when attempting to represent hierarchical data.  You'll either have a very hard time updating the table, or it will be incredibly inefficient to query against it.  My suggestion if you're going to be using such data is to consider a nested set model.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

http://www.evanpetersen.com/item/nested-sets.html

There's a bit of a learning curve, but it's worth it.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks this is realy interesting

Comment: These tables will not be updated or deleted. I would like to populate a expadable javascript list tree with the data only as parent child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Model the hierarchy with a table for each level. Bottom up:

The Expense table contains rows for Purchase, Accomodation, Maintenance, ... and a field which points to the ID field of the Ownership table.

The Ownership table contains rows ToBuy and ToLet and a field which points to the ID field of the BuildingType table.

The BuildingType table contains rows Residential and Industrial and a field that points to the AssetType table.

The AssetType Table contains rows Property and other things.

and so on.

This is called 3 normal form modelling.

Comment: This is microsoft sql server 2008